# How to rename boot options with dual boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, bios

I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed side-by-side, and the BIOS tool that's installed on the computer is called "Aptio Setup Utility". How can I rename the boot options, not just for the OS I'm using, but all of them? I.e. instead of having to log into each OS to change the boot option name, do it from BIOS somehow?

Comment: Not sure if I'm using the right terminology for "the BIOS tool installed on the computer." Whatever program lets me choose boot options when I hold f2 and start the computer... that's what I'm referring to.